# Beamer color overlay in equation environment

Tags: beamer, equations, overlays

I want to use this overly command

```
<2->\alert<2>
```

inside an equation environment to color some terms.

How can I do this?

Comment: The code snippet you wrote is quite ambiguous. What exactly are you trying to `alert` there? If you want a working example, you can find one on page 27 of the Beamer's user manual v.3.12.

Comment: You don't need to use the `overlay` environment per se. Instead, you use the overlay specification of the `\alert` command (specified by `<...>`) to define the frames on which the contents should be "alerted"/highlighted. See page 117 of the [`beamer` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You really should provide a more complete example. I'm guessing that you may be after something like the example below, but if my guess is wrong I'll delete this answer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Demo}
\Huge
  \begin{equation*}
     \alert<1->{f(x)} = \alert<2>{ax^2} + \alert<3>{bx} + \alert<4>{c}
  \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]